# Disable add to wish list and add to compare

Tags: magento2, plugin

I need to write a plugin for denying visitor to add to wish list and add to compare. But i cannot find which model and function i should refer to. I have implemented it successfully to disabling add to cart.

Following is my implementation sample for intercepting add product to cart.

Note: I do not wish to remove the block from user interface.

What type name and function should i refer to for:
1) Add to wish list
2) Add to compare
3) Send Email

For add to cart

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
        <plugin name="interceptAddingProductToCart"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cart"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Plugin Function

```
public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {
        // logic here
    }
```

Comment: You can directly disabled wishlist from the backend. Store >> Configuration >> advanced select disable for Magento_Wishlist module.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to following files for **Add to wishlist** and **Add to compare** actions.

**Add to wishlist action:** `Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add.php`

**Add to compare action:** `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add.php`

Comment: In Magento2 Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add is overriden by another core module MultipleWishlist module Magento\MultipleWishlist\Controller\Index\Add so if you want to override the wishlist add controller then you should override the MultipleWishlist add controller.